# Is it possible to catch element attribute which I clicked in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

In vue.js, I want to use element's attribute when I click the element.

In Home.vue

```
<template>
   <div role_id='1' @click="role_clicked">role 1</div>
   <div role_id='2' @click="role_clicked">role 2</div>
   <div role_id='2' @click="role_clicked">role 2</div>

   <div v-html="role_detail_box">
       axios loaded content area
   </div>
</template>
<script>
    ...
    methods: {
       role_clicked: function(){
           let uri = ~~~
           let params = { role_id : ** clicked role_id!! ** }
           axios.post(uri, params).then((response) => {
               this.role_detail_box = response.data
           })
       }
    }
</script>
```

If at jquery, I might use $(this).attr("role_id")

how to pass the html element when click a element?

Is it true I do not handle each element in vuejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    ...
    methods: {
       role_clicked: function(event){   <~~ added code here
           const role_id = event.target.getAttribute('role-id')  <~~ added code here
           let uri = ~~~
           let params = { role_id : ** clicked role_id!! ** }
           axios.post(uri, params).then((response) => {
               this.role_detail_box = response.data
           })
       }
    } 
</script>
```

The event handler in VueJS will automatically receive an `event` object which contains all the information of the target element where the event fired. Then we will use that `event` object to access the `role_id` attribute.

This line is what you need: `event.target.getAttribute('role-id')` .

Don't forget the `event` object as an input for the function:

```
role_clicked: function(event){
```

This is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/l4517y690q

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just pass that when you set the callback. e.g.

```
<div role_id='1' @click="role_clicked(1)">role 1</div>
```

And then add it to your callback function params

```
role_clicked: function(id){ ... }
```